# X-editable bootstrap loads forever even with 200

Tags: x-editable

I'm using X-editable bootstrap : http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html

The docs said :     If value is valid, you should return HTTP status 200 OK. Element on page will be updated automatically. No response body required.

And my backend was Rails 3.0.20.
From controller (on the logs), it shows it returned : Completed 200 OK in ... ms

But...
The x-editable not update the element on the page , what's going on here ???